# Should we use useCallback in every function handler in React Functional Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, arrow-functions, usecallback

let's say we have the components like this

```
const Example = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  
  const increment = () => setCounter(counter => counter + 1); 
  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={increment} />
      
      <div>{counter}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I passed the `onClick` handler as an **arrow function**, my `eslint` throw a warning:

```
error    JSX props should not use arrow functions        react/jsx-no-bind
```

As I read from an answer from this post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677733/why-shouldnt-jsx-props-use-arrow-functions-or-bind#:~:text=Why%20you%20shouldn't%20use,previous%20function%20is%20garbage%20collected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677733/why-shouldnt-jsx-props-use-arrow-functions-or-bind#:%7E:text=Why%20you%20shouldn%27t%20use,previous%20function%20is%20garbage%20collected).

The short answer is because arrow function is recreated every time, which will hurt the performance.
One solution proposed from this post is to wrapped in a **useCallback** hook, with empty array. And when I change to this, the eslint warning really disappear.

```
const Example = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  
  const increment = useCallback(() => setCounter(counter => counter + 1), []);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={increment} />
      
      <div>{counter}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, there is also another opinion saying that **overusing** useCallback will eventually slowdown the performance due to the overheads of useCallback. One example is here: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback

This is making me really confused? So for Functional Components, when dealing with inline function handler, should I just write the arrow function (ignore the eslint) or **always** wrap it in a useCallback ???

Comment: the eslint error `react/jsx-no-bind`, in my opinion, is most likely for React Component Classes, not for functional components. I may be wrong about that though. IMO it's giving you an error because it can't tell the difference between stateful and functional components

Comment: Personally, I would remove the `react/jsx-no-bind` from the eslint settings and just remember to use an autobinder in all my stateful classes, [like this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-autobind). It's easy for me to remember because my IDE allows me to have templates, so whenever I'm creating a new React class I just use my template which includes the autobinder.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

> The short answer is because arrow function is recreated every time, which will hurt the performance.

This is a common misconception. The arrow function is recreated every time **either way** (although with `useCallback` subsequent ones may be thrown away immediately). What `useCallback` does is make it possible for the child component you use the callback on to not re-render if it's memoized.

Let's look at the misconception first. Consider the `useCallback` call:

```
const increment = useCallback(() => setCounter(counter => counter + 1), []);
```

That's executed like this:

1. Evaluate the first argument, `() => setCounter(counter => counter + 1)`, **creating a function**
2. Evaluate the second argument, `[]`, creating an array
3. Call `useCallback` with those two arguments, get back a function

Compare with what you have if you don't use `useCallback`:

```
const increment = () => setCounter(counter => counter + 1);
```

That's much simpler: Create the function. It doesn't then have to do #2 and #3 above.

Let's move on to what `useCallback` actually does that's useful. Let's look at where the callback is used:

```
<Button onClick={increment} />
```

Now, suppose `Button` is memoized with [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) or similar. If `increment` changes every time your component renders, then `Button` has to re-render every time your component changes; it can't be reused between renders. But if `increment` is stable between renders (because you used `useCallback` with an empty array), the memoized result of calling `Button` can be reused, it doesn't have to be called again.

Here's an example:

```js
const { useState, useCallback } = React;

const Button = React.memo(function Button({onClick, children}) {
    console.log("Button called");
    return <button onClick={onClick}>{children}</button>;
});

function ComponentA() {
    console.log("ComponentA called");
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    // Note: Safe to use the closed-over `count` here if `count `updates are
    // triggered by clicks or similar events that definitely render, since
    // the `count` that `increment` closes over won't be stale.
    const increment = () => setCount(count + 1);
    return (
        <div>
            {count}
            <Button onClick={increment}>+</Button>
        </div>
    );
}

function ComponentB() {
    console.log("ComponentB called");
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    // Note: Can't use `count` in `increment`, need the callback form because
    // the `count` the first `increment` closes over *will* be slate after
    // the next render
    const increment = useCallback(
        () => setCount(count => count + 1),
        []
    );
    return (
        <div>
            {count}
            <Button onClick={increment}>+</Button>
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        A:
        <ComponentA />
        B:
        <ComponentB />
    </div>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Note that clicking the button in `ComponentA` always calls `Button` again, but clicking the button in `ComponentB` doesn't.

When do you want to do that? That's largely up to you, but it probably makes sense when your component's state will change frequently in ways that don't affect the contents of `increment` and thus don't affect `Button` **and** if `Button` has to do significant work when rendered. `Button` probably doesn't, but other child components may.

For instance, the `useCallback` in my previous example is probably pointless if you use `count` as the text of the button, since that means `Button` has to re-render regardless:

```js
const { useState, useCallback } = React;

const Button = React.memo(function Button({onClick, children}) {
    console.log("Button called");
    return <button onClick={onClick}>{children}</button>;
});

function ComponentA() {
    console.log("ComponentA called");
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    // Note: Safe to use the closed-over `count` here if `count `updates are
    // triggered by clicks or similar events that definitely render, since
    // the `count` that `increment` closes over won't be stale.
    const increment = () => setCount(count + 1);
    return (
        <div>
            <Button onClick={increment}>{count}</Button>
        </div>
    );
}

function ComponentB() {
    console.log("ComponentB called");
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    // Note: Can't use `count` in `increment`, need the callback form because
    // the `count` the first `increment` closes over *will* be slate after
    // the next render
    const increment = useCallback(
        () => setCount(count => count + 1),
        []
    );
    return (
        <div>
            <Button onClick={increment}>{count}</Button>
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        A:
        <ComponentA />
        B:
        <ComponentB />
    </div>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Also note that `useCallback` isn't free, it impacts the code in the callback. Look at the code in the callbacks in `ComponentA` and `ComponentB` in the examples. `ComponentA` (which doesn't use `useCallback`) can use the value of `count` that it closes over (within limits!), `() => setCount(count + 1)`. But the one in `ComponentB` always has to use the callback form of the setter, `() => setCount(count => count + 1)`. That's because if you keep using the first `increment` you create, the `count` it closes over will be stale — you'd see the count go to 1, but never further.

---

A final note: If you're re-rendering a component so often that creating and throwing away the various functions you're passing to `useCallback` or `useMemo` may be causing too much memory churn (a ***rare*** situation), you can avoid it by using a ref. Let's look at updating `ComponentB` to using a ref instead of `useCallback`:

```
const incrementRef = useRef(null);
if (!incrementRef.current /* || yourDependenciesForItChange*/) {
    // Note: Can't use `count` in `increment`, need the callback form because
    // the `count` the first `increment` closes over *will* be slate after
    // the next render
    incrementRef.current = () => setCount(count => count + 1);
}
const increment = incrementRef.current;
```

That only creates the `increment` function once (in that example, since we don't have any dependencies), it doesn't create and throw away functions like using `useCallback` does. It works because the initial value of the ref is `null`, and then the first time the component function is called, we see that it's `null`, create the function, and put it on the ref. So `increment` is only created once.

That example does recreate the function we pass `setCount` every time `increment` is called. It's possible to avoid that, too:

```
const incrementRef = useRef(null);
if (!incrementRef.current) {
    // Note: Can't use `count` in `increment`, need the callback form because
    // the `count` the first `increment` closes over *will* be slate after
    // the next render
    const incrementCallback = count => count + 1;
    incrementRef.current = () => setCount(incrementCallback);
}
const increment = incrementRef.current;
```

```js
const { useState, useRef } = React;

const Button = React.memo(function Button({onClick, children}) {
    console.log("Button called");
    return <button onClick={onClick}>{children}</button>;
});

function ComponentA() {
    console.log("ComponentA called");
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    // Note: Safe to use the closed-over `count` here if `count `updates are
    // triggered by clicks or similar events that definitely render, since
    // the `count` that `increment` closes over won't be stale.
    const increment = () => setCount(count + 1);
    return (
        <div>
            {count}
            <Button onClick={increment}>+</Button>
        </div>
    );
}

function ComponentB() {
    console.log("ComponentB called");
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    const incrementRef = useRef(null);
    if (!incrementRef.current) {
        // Note: Can't use `count` in `increment`, need the callback form because
        // the `count` the first `increment` closes over *will* be slate after
        // the next render
        const incrementCallback = count => count + 1;
        incrementRef.current = () => setCount(incrementCallback);
    }
    const increment = incrementRef.current;
    return (
        <div>
            {count}
            <Button onClick={increment}>+</Button>
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        A:
        <ComponentA />
        B:
        <ComponentB />
    </div>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

That's really going to 11 in terms of avoiding unnecessary function creation. :-)

It's a rare component that needs even that first level of optimization, much less the second level; but when/if you do, that's how you do it.

Comment: 1. In 2nd last example, why not just use `const incrementRef = () => setCount(count => count + 1);`. This will persist across re-renders.  <br/>  

2. In last example, incrementCallback and incrementRef.current are still arrow functions so they will still get recreated, isn't it?

Comment: @coder - Sorry, I don't seem to have seen that comment. 1. No, that wouldn't persist across renders; you'd get a new function on every render, which is what we're trying to avoid. 2. No, they won't get recreated, because we only create them if `incrementRef.current` is falsy, and that will only be on the *first* render.