# Parent's methods in array dependencies in useCallback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Let say we have parent and children components like this:

```js
const {useState, useCallback} = React;

const ComponentB = (props) => {
    const [text, setText] = useState('')
    const { onClick } = props

    const handleChange = useCallback((event) => {
        setText(event.target.value)
    }, [text])

    const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
        onClick(text)
    }, [onClick, text]) // Should I to take into account 'onClick' props?

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" onChange={ handleChange } />
            <button type="button" onClick={ handleClick }>Save</button>
        </div>
    )

}

const ComponentA = () => {
    const [stateA, setStateA] = useState('')

    const handleSetStateA = useCallback((state) => {
        setStateA(state)
    }, [stateA])

    return (
        <div>
            <ComponentB onClick={ handleSetStateA } />
            { stateA && `${ stateA } saved!` }
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <ComponentA />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

React [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) says that:

> every value referenced inside the callback should also appear in the dependencies array

And I'm wondering if I need to put `onClick` **method** to array dependencies in useCallback? And if so, why I should do that?

Comment: No need to add `stateA` and `text` as dependency in both component. Your `useCallback` doesn't depend on it

Comment: Thanks for doing the Stack Snippet! That's really helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And I'm wondering if I need to put `onClick` method to array dependencies in `useCallback`?

Yes.

> And if so, why I should do that?

Because it's possible that your component will get re-rendered with a new and different function for the `onClick` prop that behaves differently from the old one. Without saying it's a dependency, you'll continue using the old value.

In fact, in your given code, it's not just possible but **definite**: you create a new `handleSetStateA` function every time `stateA` changes.

That said, in `ComponentA`:

1. There's no reason to have `stateA` as a dependency in your `useCallback` creating `handleSetStateA`; `handleSetStateA` never uses `stateA`. (It uses the state setter function for it, but that's not the same thing.)
2. There's not really any reason for `handleSetStateA` at all; just pass `setStateA` directly as `onClick`. But I'm assuming you do more than *just* setting the state in that function and just left things out for the purposes of the question.

(Similarly, in `ComponentB` there's no reason for `text` to be a dependency on the `useCallback` for `handleChange`; `handleChange` doesn't use `text`.)

But even if you change `ComponentA` to pass `setStateA` directly (or at least provide a stable function), `ComponentB` shouldn't rely on `onClick` being unchanging between renders, so you'd use `onClick` in your `useCallback` dependency list regardless.

Finally: There's not much point in using `useCallback` with functions you're passing to unmemoized components. For it to be useful, the component you're providing the callback function to should be memoized (for instance, via `React.memo` or, for a `class` component, via `shouldComponentUpdate`). See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64134566/should-we-use-usecallback-in-every-function-handler-in-react-functional-componen/64134704#64134704) for details on that.

Here's an updated version of your snippet using `React.memo` and only the necessary dependencies; I've left `handleSetStateA` in (I added a `console.log` so it isn't just a wrapper):

```js
const { useState, useCallback } = React;

const ComponentB = React.memo(({ onClick }) => {
    const [text, setText] = useState("");

    const handleChange = useCallback((event) => {
        setText(event.target.value);
    }, []);

    const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
        console.log(`Handling click when text = "${text}"`);
        onClick(text);
    }, [onClick, text]);

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
            <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
                Save
            </button>
        </div>
    );
});

const ComponentA = () => {
    const [stateA, setStateA] = useState("");

    const handleSetStateA = useCallback((state) => {
        console.log(`Setting stateA to "${state}"`);
        setStateA(state);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <ComponentB onClick={handleSetStateA} />
            {stateA && `${stateA} saved!`}
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<ComponentA />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Very well explained. Thank you.