# Using useCallback for this particular code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this piece of code

```
// This is onChange event
function nameChangeHandler(e, field = 'Name') {
        const currentName = e.target.value;

        if (currentName.length >= 10) {
            if (!errors.some((x) => x.field == field)) {
                setErrors((state) => [
                    ...state,
                    {
                        field,
                        errorMessage:
                            field +
                            ' should be between 3 and 10 characters long',
                    },
                ]);
            }
        } else if (currentName.length <= 3) {
            if (!errors.some((x) => x.field == field)) {
                setErrors((state) => [
                    ...state,
                    {
                        field,
                        errorMessage:
                            field +
                            ' should be between 3 and 10 characters long',
                    },
                ]);
            }
        } else {
            setErrors((state) => state.filter((x) => x.field !== field));
        }
    }
```

This part of the code is redundant

```
  if (!errors.some((x) => x.field == field)) {
                setErrors((state) => [
                    ...state,
                    {
                        field,
                        errorMessage:
                            field +
                            ' should be between 3 and 10 characters long',
                    },
                ]);
            }
```

My question is if place it inside an useCallback hook. Will it be a good practice or it's stupid move.
Refactored code should be looking something like this:

```
const errorSetter = useCallback((field) => {
        if (!errors.some((x) => x.field == field)) {
            setErrors((state) => [
                ...state,
                {
                    field,
                    errorMessage:
                        field + ' should be between 3 and 10 characters long',
                },
            ]);
        }
    }, []);

function nameChangeHandler(e, field = 'Name') {
        const currentName = e.target.value;

        if (currentName.length >= 10) {
            errorSetter(field)
        } else if (currentName.length <= 3) {
            errorSetter(field)
        } else {
            setErrors((state) => state.filter((x) => x.field !== field));
        }
    }
```

I tried adding it in useCallback and it works fine. All though, I'm new to React and don't yet know the best practices.

Comment: useCallback come in handy when you don't want to rerender to much. Since this was originated from a stateless function, there is no need (imo).

Comment: @Stutje - I'm not sure I see what you mean. The component the OP is doing this in is clearly stateful (`errors`, `setErrors`). By making `nameChangeHandler` stable, we can avoid unnecessary re-renders of the component that the OP is passing `nameChangeHandler` to (if that component is memoized on its props). (`errorSetter`, though, can be a straight-up utility function outside the component entirely. :-) )

Answer (score 1):

**If** the component you're using `nameChangeHandler` on is memoized, there's an argument for memoizing `nameChangeHandler` (rather than `errorSetter`); details in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64134704/157247). But you could make `errorSetter` a utility function that lives outside the component, like this:

```
function errorSetter(field, setErrors) {
    setErrors((errors) => {
        if (errors.some((x) => x.field == field)) {
            return errors;
        }
        return [
            ...errors,
            {
                field,
                errorMessage: field + " should be between 3 and 10 characters long",
            },
        ];
    });
}

const YourComponent = () => {
    const nameChangeHandler = useCallback(function nameChangeHandler(e, field = "Name") {
        const currentName = e.target.value;

        if (currentName.length >= 10) {
            errorSetter(field, setErrors);
        } else if (currentName.length <= 3) {
            errorSetter(field, setErrors);
        } else {
            setErrors((state) => state.filter((x) => x.field !== field));
        }
    }, []);

    // ...
};
```

Notice how the utility function doesn't rely on anything it closes over, it just uses the `field` and `setErrors` it's passed; and the only thing `nameChangeHandler` uses that it closes over is `setErrors`, which is guaranteed to be stable. So `nameChangeHandler` can be memoized via `useCallback` (or `useMemo`, or `useRef`, which are other ways of doing it).

By making `nameChangeHandler` stable, you avoid unnecessary re-renders of the component you pass it to — **if** that component is memoized.

---

> If I use `setErrors()` the component will re-render...

Usually, yes, but not necessarily. Here's what [the documentation for functional (callback) updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) says *(my emphasis)*, but keep reading, it's oversimplifying a bit:

> If your update function returns the exact same value as the current state, **the subsequent rerender will be skipped completely**.

More accurately, the *first* time you set identical state, your component function will get called again, but unless something is different the render stops there. From that point forward, if you set identical state, a "fast bail-out" optimization means it doesn't even call your component function.

Here's an example of that:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const lowerCaseA = "a".charCodeAt(0);

let renderCounter = 0;
const Example = () => {
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);

    console.log(`Render #${++renderCounter}, errors = ${errors.join(", ")}`);
    const setSameValue = () => {
        // Call `setErrors`, but have it return the array that's already in state
        setErrors((errors) => errors);
    };
    const setDifferentValue = () => {
        // Call `setErrors`, have it create and return a new new array
        setErrors((errors) => [...errors, String.fromCharCode(lowerCaseA + errors.length)]);
    };
    return (
        <div>
            Errors: {errors.join(", ")}
            <div>
                <input type="button" value="Set Same Value" onClick={setSameValue} />
                <input type="button" value="Set Different Value" onClick={setDifferentValue} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

In that, if you click **Set Different Value**, naturally the component re-renders, since we're returning a different array. (The fact the array's contents change isn't really relevant.)

In contrast, if you click **Set Same Value**, we're setting the same array that's already there. You'll notice that the first time, your component function is called to render (but child components aren't), and if you click it again, even your component function isn't called. (See the discussion in [this closed issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20817) for why there's a distinction between the first time and subsequent times.)

> ...I had problem with the code where if a word is longer than 10 characters for every character (after the 10th) it would add another object to the state which I didn't need because it was duplicate. That's why I put the if statement with `some()`. If I have memoized the `nameChangeHandler` would that problem have been solved...

You still need that check (it's in the code above), memoization doesn't change that. But in the normal case, it won't cause a re-render.

Comment: I think I understand but to clarify. If I use setErrors() the component will re-render. I had problem with the code where if a word is longer than 10 characters for every character (after the 10th) it would add another object to the state which I didn't need because it was duplicate. That's why I put the if statement with some(). If I have memoized the nameChangeHandler would that problem have been solved or I dont quite get the grasp of it? I'm very appreciative of your answer and thank you very much.

Comment: @Azzarox - I've updated the answer to respond to those questions, hope that helps! :-)

Comment: Yes, I see now. I think I understood a little better. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

It can be simplified using or operation like:

```js
function nameChangeHandler(e, field = 'Name') {
    const currentName = e.target.value;

    if (currentName.length >= 10 || currentName.length <= 3) {
        if (!errors.some((x) => x.field == field)) {
            setErrors((state) => [
                ...state,
                {
                    field,
                    errorMessage:
                        field +
                        ' should be between 3 and 10 characters long',
                },
            ]);
        }
    } else {
        setErrors((state) => state.filter((x) => x.field !== field));
    }
}
```

to reduce redundant code. I don't think `useCallback` is what you need here. The only usage of `useCallback` I can imagine here is to wrap the whole function in `useCallback` to avoid re-rendering the element you're passing it to.

Comment: Yes, you are right. However, I was wondering in what cases would be good to use useCallback and if this is a good case or a possible one. I'm still new to React and trying to understand it. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: as we all know when a component's prop is changed that component re-renders itself. when we create a function in component body of ComponentA and pass it to a child component (ComponentB), everytime ComponentA is re-rendered, a new function is created and passed to ComponentB. it means ComponentB receives a new prop so it's going to be re-rendered again. but on the other side we normally like to avoid unnecessary re-renders. `useCallback` is useful in this case because it can store and return same the function when ComponentA is re-rendered. so ComponentB will not be re-rendered.