# Anonymous function vs named function on event handlers

Tags: reactjs

I've been searching around for a long time, but I coudn't find out. Can anyone tell me if there is (and if there is, what is the) difference between using anonymous or named function on event handlers?

Example 1:

```
...
onClick={() => toggleStatus(!status)}
```

Example 2:

```
function handleToggleStatus() {
  toggleStatus(!status);
}
...
onClick={handleToggleStatus}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short version: No, there isn't (at least in a React-specific way; one nice thing about named functions is that they have *names*, which can be handy in call stacks / stack traces).

The long version: The reason you may have seen people saying not to do `onClick={() => toggleStatus(!status)}` isn't that it's an anonymous function; it's that it's a function that gets re-created on every render. That means that the component it's being used on sees a different function on every render. **If** that component is memoized on its props and your component is being re-rendered for reasons unrelated to that component, that can be unnecessary work. In that case, you might want to use `useCallback` to have a stable function you can provide to the component:

```
const handleToggleStatus = useCallback(
    () => toggleStatus((status) => !status), // Assuming it allows functional updates
    []
);
```

Or:

```
const handleToggleStatus = useCallback(
    () => toggleStatus(!status), // If it doesn't allow functional updates
    [status] // <== Note dependency
);
```

Those functions are anonymous and recreated every time,¹ but `useCallback` will return the earlier version if the dependencies haven't changed as a performance optimization, allowing a memoized component to avoid re-rendering.

More about `useCallback` (and `useMemo` and such) and memoization in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64134704/157247).

---

¹ *"Those functions are anonymous and recreated every time..."* They don't *have* to be anonymous, there's no reason you can't use a named function expression:

```
const handleToggleStatus = useCallback(
    function handleToggleStatus() { toggleStatus((status) => !status); }, // Assuming it allows functional updates
    []
);
```

Or:

```
const handleToggleStatus = useCallback(
    function handleToggleStatus() { toggleStatus(!status); }, // If it doesn't allow functional updates
    [status] // <== Note dependency
);
```

Comment: It is now clear. Thank you so much!