# Why is this simple React component re-rendering despite none of its parameters changing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a fairly simple React component which renders two components within it: one is a big list and another is a modal. When a button within the list is clicked, the modal appears. This process is causing the list component to re-render, thus inducing the lag. There is a gap in my React knowledge as to why this is happening.

Here's the code:

```
const ExistingMargins = ({ margins }) => {

    const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);
    const [marginBeingEdited, setMarginBeingEdited] = useState();

    return (
        <>
            <TableRows
                margins={margins}
                onEditButtonClicked={(marginToEdit) => {
                    setMarginBeingEdited(marginToEdit);
                    setIsModalOpen(true);
                }}
            />

            <EditModal
                isModalOpen={isModalOpen}
                closeModal={() => setIsModalOpen(false)}
                margin={marginBeingEdited}
            />
        </>
    );
};

const TableRows = ({ margins, onEditButtonClicked }) => {
    return (
        <table>
            {margins.map(margin => (
                <tr key={margin.Id}>
                    <td>{margin.Name}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button onClick={() => onEditButtonClicked(margin)}>Edit</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            ))}
        </table>
    );
};
```

**My understanding:** is that React applies a unique key to the two components being rendered here (`TableRows` and `EditModal`) and that, whenever any state variable changes, the component re-renders and updates the shadow-DOM. React then compares the new and previous shadow-DOM to detect changes. Any changes get rendered in the actual-DOM. Since nothing in `TableRows` is changing, no laggy updates to the actual-DOM happens.

This isn't the case. Here's what is actually happening:

- The user clicks the **Edit** button in the `TableRows` component
- The `isModalOpen` and `marginBeingEdited` state variables in the parent component get updated
- The entire `ExistingMargins` component re-renders
- ...including the `TableRows` component, which causes lag

My understanding is that `TableRows` shouldn't re-render on the actual-DOM because no state variables being passed to it have changed.

This is not happening. I can see in Chrome's React Profiler that there's a big, slow re-render of the table rows.

Why is this happening? Memoisation might fix it, but where is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: `I can see in Chrome's React Profiler that there's a big, slow re-render of the table rows.` By the way, the development build of react runs a *lot* of extra code to help with debugging, so the profiler may look slow now but be fine in a production build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on:

1. `TableRows` isn't memo-ized (via `React.memo` for instance, since it's a function component; for a class component you'd inherit from `React.PureComponent`). Non-memoized components re-render if their parent re-renders, even if their props don't change.

   But also:
2. Its props **are** changing, because of this code:

   ```
   onEditButtonClicked={(marginToEdit) => {
       setMarginBeingEdited(marginToEdit);
       setIsModalOpen(true);
   }}
   ```

   That creates a **new** function every time the parent is rendered, so `TableRows` sees a changed prop.

To solve that:

1. Memoize the component
2. Create the function *once* and reuse it (via `useCallback`, `useMemo`, or `useRef`)

See my answer to [*Should we use useCallback in every function handler in React Functional Components?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64134704/157247) for more details.

---

Side note re:

> My understanding is that TableRows shouldn't re-render on the actual-DOM because no state variables being passed to it have changed.

I think the term you're looking for there is "commit," not render. When React *renders* your component, your component function is called and returns an element tree. React then *commits* that tree to the DOM (doing a diff and only making the necessary changes).

Comment: I had a feeling it was due to the anonymous function but didn't think to use `useCallback` to solve it. I also didn't know that `useMemo` was necessary to prevent useless re-renders; I thought it did that automatically. Thanks for taking the time to write this up rather than just saying "use memo", I appreciate it 

Comment: @MSOACC - My pleasure, glad that helped! [Did you mean `React.memo` (rather than `useMemo`)?]

Comment: Nah I meant that I was expecting someone to just glance over the question and tell me to "use memoisation". It was the deeper understanding that I needed resolving.

Comment: @MSOACC - Sorry, I meant here: *"I also didn't know that `useMemo` was necessary to prevent useless re-renders"* `useMemo` isn't *necessary* to avoid re-renders, but it's one way (along with `useCallback` and `useRef`) to avoid making props change, which is necessary for avoiding re-renders. :-) For instance, in your code while you could use `useMemo`, `useCallback` would probably be simpler.