# Is there any wrong with my interface create and assignment?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm new in to build a web with React Libray, and use next.js with typscript to create the web app.
And I'm trying to build a todo list web app.

I create an interface for collet the list data like below:

```
interface listData {
  text: string,
  isDone: boolean,
  viewMode?: { display: '' },
  editMode?: { display: 'none' },
}

const [list, setList] = useState<listData[]>([]);

const addList = (item: any) => {
  if (item !== "") {
    const newList = [...list, { text: item, isDone: false, viewMode: { display: '' }, editMode: { display: 'none' } }];
    localStorage.setItem('listData', JSON.stringify([...list, { text: item, isDone: false, viewMode: { display: '' }, editMode: { display: 'none' } }]));
    setList(newList);
  };
}
```

I got the error on vscode down below when I setList(newList):

```
Argument of type '(listData | { text: string; isDone: boolean; viewMode: { display: string; }; editMode: { display: string; }; })[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<listData[]>'.
  Type '(listData | { text: string; isDone: boolean; viewMode: { display: string; }; editMode: { display: string; }; })[]' is not assignable to type 'listData[]'.
    Type 'listData | { text: string; isDone: boolean; viewMode: { display: string; }; editMode: { display: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'listData'.
      Type '{ text: string; isDone: boolean; viewMode: { display: string; }; editMode: { display: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'listData'.
        The types of 'viewMode.display' are incompatible between these types.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type '""'.ts(2345)
```

The viewMode and editMode is build for display css to show which tag will be show,
like when user press the edit button, then the viewmode.display: 'none', otherwise editMode.display: 'none'.

And now I got a problem about addList assignment problem, please look at the image.
I not sure what the prolem is now in addList function when I setList(newList).
Hope someone can tell me where am I worng, and really thanks for it.

```
return (
  <>
    <div className={styles.bodyOuterDiv} >
      ...
        <ul >
          {list.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <li key={index} className={styles.todoListOuterLi} >
                <div className={item.isDone ? styles.todoListItemsWithIsDone : styles.todoListItems} style={item.viewMode}>
                        {item.text}
                </div>
                <textarea className={styles.todoListTextArea} value={item.text} onChange={(e) => { setItem(e.target.value) }} style={item.editMode} />
                      ...
               </li>
             );
          })}
        </ul>
       ...
     </div>
  </>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that because you don't have a type annotation on `newList` or the new object in it, TypeScript *infers* the types of those properties from the types of the property values. When it does that, TypeScript infers `""` and `"none"` to be of type `string` (rather than the string literal types `""` and `"none"`), but your interface requires the string literal types `""` and `"none"`.

There are a couple of ways to fix it. Probably the most direct is to tell TypeScript that `newList` is a `listData[]` (but keep reading, there are a couple of other issues):

```typescript
const addList = (item: any) => {
    if (item !== "") {
        const newList: listData[] = [ // <===========
            ...list,
            { text: item, isDone: false, viewMode: { display: "" }, editMode: { display: "none" } },
        ];
        localStorage.setItem(
            "listData",
            JSON.stringify([
                ...list,
                {
                    text: item,
                    isDone: false,
                    viewMode: { display: "" },
                    editMode: { display: "none" },
                },
            ])
        );
        setList(newList);
    }
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN1wC+cAZlBCHAERTo4DGMVA3AFCvAB2+UJDBAG2CoYAETw5ErODLj4AHjABccEVC4BzNrLjDRETuhUAjCBAF1O22QDdg6AO4BZCABN0AfhVJXwsAJwATxUqKiJrGXRfGBd3L0Q4X1R-IJDOA3QwwjZCdnoDETgAbSERABpVdBgAGWEYAF04AF4UDGw8dAAeUrEJIvqAPgAKfoBKNlZ8zkKcV1dawpah4HwQFRxOQNHmgakdYBI4ZdW4AEImltDthGkdWSnCwwcF5Tge8Vx+5uK4AHpfuCdC7AkEXW53O4AOmhPTK4IhsiQCleK3QIAqegyKj4AgwFTsjliRgSSRSwWoWQqURWRO8iT8AXJVHShiyRDhCLg9QidwEEHoOAE2GgOA06EhGBgAElVkN4ZyqO8JFQOZzZAApTAAeQAchKYOpOBoDoERvK1TJoZDYeaLTcLRbkSpUejbQ6ZJjDNjBXi3e6Cc43MSfAzUhT2X6HdSYkG6aTGWkMpTIxDCKqLfVRm7xm7JS8hk8XjmdLlsqwgA)

---

Side note: The `item` parameter's type should be `string`, not `any`:

```typescript
const addList = (item: string) => {
    // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^
```

By making it `any`, you leave yourself open to doing `addList(42)`, which will put an object in your list with `text: 42`, which isn't what the type says it will be.

---

That said, a couple of other things:

1. Whenever you're setting state based on existing state, ti's best to use the callback form of the state setter rather than relying on the copy of `list` that `addList` closes over, because that can be stale.
2. There's no reason to repeat the code adding the new item, just use `newList` when storing in local storage.

So:

```typescript
const addList = (item: string) => {
    if (item !== "") {
        setList((list) => {
            const newList: listData[] = [
                ...list,
                {
                    text: item,
                    isDone: false,
                    viewMode: { display: "" },
                    editMode: { display: "none" },
                },
            ];
            localStorage.setItem("listData", JSON.stringify(newList));
            return newList;
        });
    }
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN1wC+cAZlBCHAERTo4DGMVA3AFCvAB2+UJDBAG2CoYAETw5ErODLj4AHjABccEVC4BzNrLjDRETuhUAjCBAF1O22QDdg6AO4BZCABN0AfhVJXwsAJwATxUqKiJrGXRfGBd3L0Q4X1R-IJDOA3QwwjZCdnoDETgAbSERABpVdBgAGWEYAF04AF4UDGw8dAAeUrEJIvqAPgAKfoBKNlZ8zkKcV1dawpah4HwQFTVNUeaBqR1gEjhl1bgAQiaW0K2EaR1ZDBq6oaGeraad69vPuCnCwwcF5RwHriXD9ZrFG5fL4AOlhPTKkKhtw+SNRCkBK3QIARqNRegyKj4AgwONxULsjliRgSSRSwWoWVJZM+URWVO8iT8AXpVHShkZiLJhCZSPqESRAgg9BwAmw0BwGnQ0PuAElVkMqMCJFQKgApTAAeQAcsqYOpOBp9oEhn8AaNxoKvrQYMgoJw4La6uKdIQHT7WNkgA)

Using the callback form also lets you memoize `addList`, which could be useful if the component you're passing it to is memoized. Giving that component a new `addList` every time forces it to re-render, whereas if `addList` is stable (because it's memoized), the component may be able to avoid re-rendering. But whether you want to memoize `addList` depends on the component you're giving it to. (More about that in my answer about `useCallback` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64134704/157247).)

Answer (score 0):

A fix for the first error with the type:

```
  const newItem: listData = { text: item, isDone: false, viewMode: { display: '' }, editMode: { display: 'none' } }
  const newList = [...list, newItem];
```