# UseCallback(), which variables to add to the dependency array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, functional-programming

UseCallback(), are function paramaters always added ot the dependency array in default? whereas variables used directly wihtin the function's body should only be added if I am sure they would be updated?

```
const User = ({}) => { 
 const [state, setState] = useState(1); 
 const randomVariable = 1;
 
 const handle = useCallback((state) => { 
 const User = setState(state + randomVariable) 
 }, [state]); 
 return ( )
})
```

- Should both "state" and "randomVariable" be added to its dependency array?
- will "state" always be 'automatically added' (by the compiler?) to the dependency array because it's in the function's arguments?
- Whereas "randomVariable" has to be manually added to the dependency array (by me) depending on whether I plan to have "randomVariable" update frequently?

Comment: `state` should be neither a dependency nor a parameter, since you are not using it within the function.

Comment: The dependency array should contain variables that are used within the useCallback function .  "state" in this case is not used, so it is not needed as a dependency .

Comment: @Bergi you are correct, I forgot to add it to the example. Otherwise my question is the same

Comment: @RobDubParker what about the "randomVariable" should it be added to the dependency array only if i am sure its value would be updated outside?

Comment: @Bergi I edited the example, I understand what you meant. What about "randomvariable" though?

Comment: @giveback Having `randomParameter` as a dependency does not make sense. It does not exist outside of the function, it is only passed when you call it!

Comment: @Bergi My bad! I was planning to use a `randomProp` added to the component and then used in the function instead of the whole parameter thing. I hope the example is correct now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any variable (or similar) that your callback function [*closes over*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) should be in the dependency array, since if they aren't, an old version of the callback function closing over a previous variable (or similar) will be reused, causing bugs.

- `state` - In your example, `state` isn't something the function *closes over*. it's a parameter to the function. (It has the same name as a variable the function would close over, but because you've declared it as a function parameter, that takes precedence — *shadows* — the outer declaration.) Since that parameter is something your callback *receives* when called, rather than closing over, it doesn't belong in the dependency array.
- `randomVariable` - Your callback *does* close over `randomVariable`, so it needs to be in the dependency array so you're getting an up-to-date version of your callback when it changes, rather than continuing to use a stale version of your callback using a stale version of the variable.

So:

```
const User = ({}) => { 
    const [state, setState] = useState(); 
    const randomVariable = /*...presumably something here other than just 0...*/;
    
    const handle = useCallback((state) => { 
        const User = setState(state + randomVariable) 
    }, [randomVariable]); 
    return /*...*/;
});
```

**If** `state` weren't a parameter to the callback and you wanted to use the one the function closes over, it would also need to be in the dependency list, but your function doesn't seem at first glance to need to use the `state` state member.

You may find my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64134704/157247) handy, it goes into more general detail on `useCallback`.

Comment: "closes over" should mean having it inside the function's body I assume?
Yeah I forgot to use the "state" paramater, as mentioned by others, I edited it.

So basically, anything that is a parameter shouldn't necessarily be in the dependency array. Whereas anything that the function "closes over" should be in the dependency array... even if i am sure that the later won't ever be updated?

Comment: @giveback - LOL, I was editing in a link for "closes over" as you posted your comment. Basically, if the function uses a variable (or similar) that it has access to because of *where* the function was created (rather than receiving it as a parameter, or having it as a local variable), the function *closes over* that variable. Not only don't you need to include the function's parameters, but you *can't* -- the `state` you'd include in your example isn't the parameter, it's something else entirely that just happens to have the same name. Re dependencies that never change: Whether you...

Comment: ...include them is up to you; if they never change, you won't have bugs as a result of having a stale copy of them. **But**, if they never change, putting them in the dependency array is harmless (checking that they haven't changed doesn't take enough time to worry about). Including them also has the benefits that A) If the code changes in the future and the variable *does* change, you don't suddenly have a bug as a result; and B) It'll stop React-aware linters complaining at you about missing dependencies. :-) But for instance, state setters (like `setState` in your example) never...

Comment: ...change (they're *stable* across renders), so it's normal to leave them out (and linters know that so they don't bother you about them).

Comment: @Crowder ...*facepalms* you are right! dunno how I missed that part, should have used something else as a parameter name...
I see! this was really helpful especially the additional part about the state setters. This was the answer I needed.

Comment: @giveback - Great, glad that helped! FYI, I rolled the question back to where it was when I wrote the answer, since otherwise when people come along later, the stuff about the `state` parameter in the answer wouldn't make any sense to people. :-)

Comment: @Crowder fair enough!

Answer (score 1):

> ##### [To remove a dependency, prove that it's not a dependency](https://react.dev/learn/removing-effect-dependencies#to-remove-a-dependency-prove-that-its-not-a-dependency)
>
> Notice that you can’t “choose” the dependencies of your Effect. Every
> [reactive
> value](https://react.dev/learn/lifecycle-of-reactive-effects#all-variables-declared-in-the-component-body-are-reactive)
> used by your Effect’s code must be declared in your dependency list.
> The dependency list is determined by the surrounding code:
>
> ```
> const serverUrl = 'https://localhost:1234';
>
> function ChatRoom({ roomId }) { // This is a reactive value
>   useEffect(() => {
>     const connection = createConnection(serverUrl, roomId); // This Effect reads that reactive value
>     connection.connect();
>     return () => connection.disconnect();
>   }, [roomId]); // ✅ So you must specify that reactive value as a dependency of your Effect
>   // ...
> }
> ```
>
> Reactive values include props and all variables and functions declared
> directly inside of your component. Since roomId is a reactive value,
> you can’t remove it from the dependency list. The linter wouldn’t
> allow it:
>
> ```
> const serverUrl = 'https://localhost:1234';
>
> function ChatRoom({ roomId }) {
>   useEffect(() => {
>     const connection = createConnection(serverUrl, roomId);
>     connection.connect();
>     return () => connection.disconnect();
>   }, []); //  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'roomId'
>   // ...
> }
> ```
>
> And the linter would be right! Since roomId may change over time, this
> would introduce a bug in your code.
>
> To remove a dependency, “prove” to the linter that it doesn’t need to
> be a dependency. For example, you can move roomId out of your
> component to prove that it’s not reactive and won’t change on
> re-renders:
>
> ```
> const serverUrl = 'https://localhost:1234';
> const roomId = 'music'; // ✅ Not a reactive value anymore
>
> function ChatRoom() {
>   useEffect(() => {
>     const connection = createConnection(serverUrl, roomId);
>     connection.connect();
>     return () => connection.disconnect();
>   }, []); // ✅ All dependencies declared
>   // ...
> }
> ```

(source: [react.dev docs](https://react.dev/learn/separating-events-from-effects))