# Can we set default value of a variable as empty arrow function while destructuring in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, arrow-functions, destructuring

I was working on a react project and came accross this situation.
Is it okay to set an empty arrow function to a variable while destructuring in javascript.
Are there any cons if done like this ?

`const { onClick = () => {} } = props;`

Answer (score 1):

Doing this will assign the empty function to onClick if there if props does not have an onClick key. So while this is a legal method to have a default value for a prop key which might not be guaranteed to exist, the cons of doing this will have to be evaluated by you in the context of your app.

Answer (score 1):

In *general* that's okay, if you really want `onClick` to be a do-nothing function when it either doesn't exist on `props` or it has the value `undefined`. Specifically in the context of a React component, though:

- The majority of the time, the component you'd be passing `onClick` to afterward will expect that it may get `undefined` for the function prop, so there's not much point in defaulting it.
- By doing this, you're creating a **new** function every time, which means that any component you pass `onClick` to will see it as a new value and have to re-render, even if it's memoized and could avoid re-rendering if `onClick` hadn't changed. In that case, again, `undefined` would be the better choice, since it would avoid unnecessary re-renders.

Here's a simple example showing the effect of the unstable function reference on a memoized component:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const MemoizedComponent = React.memo(({ onClick, label }) => {
    console.log(`${label} rendering`);
    return (
        <button type="button" onClick={onClick}>
            {label}
        </button>
    );
});

const Example = (props) => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    const { onClick1 } = props;
    const { onClick2 = () => {} } = props;
    return (
        <div>
            <div>Counter: {counter}</div>
            <input
                type="button"
                value="+"
                onClick={() => setCounter((c) => c + 1)}
            />
            <MemoizedComponent onClick={onClick1} label="Button 1" />
            <MemoizedComponent onClick={onClick2} label="Button 2" />
        </div>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Notice how "Button 2" renders every time you click `+`, but "Button 1" doesn't. That's because "Button 2" gets `onClick2` which we're defaulting to `() => {}`, but "Button 1" gets `onClick1` which we're leaving as `undefined`.

[My other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64134566/should-we-use-usecallback-in-every-function-handler-in-react-functional-componen/64134704#64134704) has more about how/why unstable function references cause unnecessary re-rendering of memoized components.