# React, useCallback updates a state variable that is also present in its dependency array, how does it prevent infinite re-rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Consider the following code**

```
import { useMemo, useState, useCallback } from 'react'


function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    setCount(count + 1);

  }, [count]);

  return <div>
    <Child onClick={handleClick} />
  </div>
}


function Child({onClick}) {
  return (
    <button onClick={onClick}>Click here</button>
  )
}

export default App
```

In the above code, when the button with the text 'Click here' is clicked, the count state variable gets updated which is also a dependency in useCallback which is passed as a handler to onClick attribute of the button.

Comment: FWIW, you can (and probably should, if you're going to use `useCallback` at all in that code) remove that dependency and use the callback form of the setter instead: `const handleClick = useCallback(() => setCount((c) => c + 1)), []);` Whether you need to use `useCallback` depends on how expensive it is to render `Child`, more in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64134566/should-we-use-usecallback-in-every-function-handler-in-react-functional-componen/64134704#64134704).

Comment: Agreed @T.J.Crowder, for this example, I can get rid of useCallback entirely. However if I understand it correctly, the callback form of setter is to make sure we get correct results as the state is asynchronous?

Comment: Yes, the state is asynchronous, so using the callback form of the setter comes to the rescue here - see the official example https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state.

However, it also has another advantage, it allows you to remove the state from the dependency array, since it can be accessed using the callback form of the setter, and that might be useful in many situations. I believe this is what @T.J.Crowder wanted to emphasize.

Comment: @N.Pamnani - That's another thing the callback form does, yes, it protects you from possibly using stale state as the basis of new state (that is, `setCount(count + 1)` could use a stale `count` and therefore do an incorrect update). But because it frees you from using `count` at all (you get a parameter in the callback instead), it means your function no longer depends on `count` and can be stable for the duration of your component's lifecycle. So you get *two* benefits. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `count` get changed by your `handleClick`, indeed now since `count` is a dependency of this `useCallback`, react will throw away the old `handleClick` and creates a new one in the new render that happened. So that's it, a change in the dependency of a `useCallback` just throws away the old callback and gives you a new one..

Infinite renders on the other hand usually happen if you're updating a state a in a `useEffect` that also has this state as deps. Example:

```js
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
useEffect(() => {
    setCount(count + 1);
}, [count]);  // this is bad, don't do it
```

So this is the distinction, a `useEffect` runs its body when the deps change, but `useCallback` does not run its body when the deps change, it just gives you a new function, and this new function can now see the new deps, in your case, the new `handleClick` will have access to the newest `count` state.

Comment: So is it safe to say this - 
useCallback will give you the cachedFuncton on every re-render, until one of its dependency gets changed and then, the new function definition is cached ?

Comment: exactly! @N.Pamnani

Comment: Thanks @HadiElYakhni. Got the concept now.